# Construct and pass dataframes between callbacks after clicking a button in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to add an item after a button is clicked. After clicking several buttons (`A`, `B`, `C`), the dataframe should have those information passed after the selected buttons are clicked. I want the passed dataframe to include `df = pd.DataFrame( combination of A, B, C)`. However, at this stage, when I press the button, and write the corresponding information into a dataframe, the callback deletes all the information, and keeps only the last pressed button. I bypassed this limitation by writing corresponding information into `csv` but I wonder if there is a more elegant approach.

```
@app.callback(Output('intermediate_value', 'children'),
            [Input('like_val_0', 'n_clicks_timestamp'),
            Input('like_val_1','n_clicks_timestamp'),
            Input('like_val_2', 'n_clicks_timestamp')
            ])

def construct_preferences(like_val_0, like_val_1, like_val_2):
    listedTimestamps = [like_val_0, like_val_1, like_val_2]
    listedTimestamps = [0 if v is None else v for v in listedTimestamps]
    sortedTimestamps = sorted(listedTimestamps)


    if like_val_0 == sortedTimestamps[-1]:
        pickedButton = "like_val_0"
        print (pickedButton)
        sample_that_matches_address_0 = data[data['addresses'].str.contains(item_in_df[0].partition('.jpg')[0])]
        sample_that_matches_address_0.to_csv('prefs.csv', columns=list(data), mode='a', header=False)

    if like_val_1 == sortedTimestamps[-1]:
        pickedButton = "like_val_1"
        print (pickedButton)
        sample_that_matches_address_1 = data[data['addresses'].str.contains(item_in_df[1].partition('.jpg')[0])]
        sample_that_matches_address_1.to_csv('prefs.csv', columns=list(data), mode='a', header=False)

    if like_val_2 == sortedTimestamps[-1]:
        pickedButton = "like_val_2"
        print (pickedButton)
        sample_that_matches_address_2 = data[data['addresses'].str.contains(item_in_df[2].partition('.jpg')[0])]
        sample_that_matches_address_2.to_csv('prefs.csv', columns=list(data), mode='a', header=False)
```

As you can see I write that item to `csv` and I wonder if there is any way to prevent callback from updating until I press another button; in my case `predict`.

```
@app.callback(Output('container', 'children'), 
            [Input('intermediate_value', 'children'),
            Input('predict_val', 'n_clicks')])
def update_output_images (intermediate_value, n_clicks):

    if (n_clicks!=0):

        preferences = pd.read_csv('prefs.csv')
        preferences.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
```

EDIT:
As the comment suggests, I update the example with a reproducible one

```
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
import random
import glob 
from os import listdir
import flask
import pickle
import base64
from PIL import Image as PImage
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server


data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

preferences = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(data))

row_1 = html.Div([(dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([
                                html.P('Random_val_0 is {}'.format(data['A'].loc[0])),
                                dbc.Button('Like This One', id='like_val_0', style={'vertical-align': "bottom"}, n_clicks=0),
                            ]),
                            dbc.Col([
                                html.P('Random_val_1 is {}'.format(data['A'].loc[1])),
                                dbc.Button('Like This One', id='like_val_1', style={'vertical-align': "bottom"}, n_clicks=0),
                            ]),
                            dbc.Col([
                                html.P('Random_val_2 is {}'.format(data['A'].loc[2])),
                                dbc.Button('Like This One', id='like_val_2', style={'vertical-align': "bottom"}, n_clicks=0),
                            ])
                ]))])

predict =  html.Div([
                    html.Button ('Predict', id='predict_val', n_clicks=0), 
                    html.Div(id='images_new')  
                ])
container_out = html.Div([html.Div(id='container')])
placeholder = html.Div([html.Div(id='intermediate_value', style={'display': 'none'})])                


app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[row_1, html.Br(), html.Br(), placeholder, html.Br(), container_out, html.Br(), predict])

@app.callback(Output('intermediate_value', 'children'), 
            [Input('like_val_0', 'n_clicks_timestamp'),
            Input('like_val_1','n_clicks_timestamp'),
            Input('like_val_2', 'n_clicks_timestamp')
            ])

def construct_preferences(like_val_0,like_val_1, like_val_2):
    listedTimestamps = [like_val_0, like_val_1, like_val_2]
    listedTimestamps = [0 if v is None else v for v in listedTimestamps]
    sortedTimestamps = sorted(listedTimestamps)

    if like_val_0 == sortedTimestamps[-1]:
        pickedButton = "like_val_0"
        print (pickedButton)
        sample_output_0 = data.loc[data['A'] == data['A'].loc[0]]
        return sample_output_0.to_json()
        #sample_that_matches_address_0.to_csv('prefs.csv', columns=list(data), mode='a', header=False)

    if like_val_1 == sortedTimestamps[-1]:
        pickedButton = "like_val_1"
        print (pickedButton)
        sample_output_1 = data.loc[data['A'] == data['A'].loc[1]]
        return sample_output_1.to_json()


    if like_val_2 == sortedTimestamps[-1]:
        pickedButton = "like_val_2"
        print (pickedButton)
        sample_output_2 = data.loc[data['A'] == data['A'].loc[2]]
        return sample_output_2.to_json()

@app.callback(Output('container', 'children'), 
            [Input('intermediate_value', 'children'),
            Input('predict_val', 'n_clicks')])
def update_output_images (intermediate_value, n_clicks):

    if (n_clicks!=0):

        preferences = pd.read_json(intermediate_value)
        print (preferences.shape)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: Could you post a complete example, i.e. an app that runs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot; the rest of app invokes trained ML models that predict the content of `preferences`. On top of that, the content is read in from `csv`

Comment: I understand. In that case, I would recommend that you create a small example app that demonstrates the issue that you are facing. It would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: From you example, it seems that you are replacing the "intermediate_value" with the new one rather than appending it to the previous data, similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928923/dash-app-call-back-append-new-entry-in-data-frame-and-replace-if-matches-with-an. Does the answer help you?

Comment: Hey @emher. Thank you for providing a link. Unfortunately, I still have issues with my code.